# How to pass the value inputted in a textbox to an API request value?

Tags: php, api

I'm working with API, I always hardcode the value I passed but now I want the value to come from what is inputted in a textbox.

This is the sample API request I'm trying to submit:

```
    $billTo = new stdClass();
$billTo->firstName = "John";
$billTo->lastName = "Doe";
$billTo->street1 = "1st street";
$billTo->city = "Bangalore";
$billTo->state = "KA";
$billTo->postalCode = "94043";
$billTo->country = "IN";
$billTo->email = "null@gmail.com";
$request->billTo = $billTo;
```

This is what I'm trying to do to get the value in the textbox.

My Form.php:

```
    <form id="Form" name="Form" action="api.php" 
    method="post" target="paInlineFrame">

    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php $billTo_firstName;?>" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<?php $billTo_lastName;?>" />
    <input type="text" name="street1" value="<?php $billTo_street1;?>" />
    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php $billTo_city;?>" />
    <input type="text" name="state" value="<?php $billTo_state;?>" />
    <input type="text" name="postalCode" value="<?php $billTo_postalCode;?>" />
    <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php $billTo_country;?>" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php $billTo_email;?>" />  

   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
```

My api.php:

```
    $billTo = new stdClass();
    $billTo->firstName = $_POST["billTo_firstName"];
    $billTo->lastName = $_POST["billTo_lastName"];
    $billTo->street1 = $_POST["billTo_street1"];
    $billTo->city = $_POST["billTo_city"];
    $billTo->state = $_POST["billTo_state"];
    $billTo->postalCode = $_POST["billTo_postalCode"];
    $billTo->country = $_POST["billTo_country"];
    $billTo->email = $_POST["billTo_email"];
    $request->billTo = $billTo;
```

I only got an error of: Notice: Undefined index: billTo_firstName in /storage/ssd4/317/1753317/public_html/api.php on line 3 ,etc.
I also tried different method other than this but all failed.

Hope you can help I'm really lost. Thank you!

Comment: The keys for your `$_POST` values would be the same as the name attributes specified in your form elements. So instead, this should work: `$_POST["firstName"];`

Comment: And in addition to @matt comment, I think that is a good practice to check if any key exists using coleasing ternary operator  `??` like: `$billTo->firstName = $_POST["firstName"] ?? '';`

Comment: I see it should be the name attributes, noted with thanks Matt!!!!

Comment: Sorry, what is a coleasing ternary operator? @Alex

Comment: I've mentioned it: `??`. Instead of  `isset($_POST["firstName"]) ? $_POST["firstName"] : "";` you can just `$_POST["firstName"] ?? "";` http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the text area's `name` property in in PHP's `$_POST` should work.

You should replace your api.php code snippet into this:

```
$billTo = new stdClass();
$billTo->firstName  = isset($_POST["firstName"]) ? $_POST["firstName"] : "";
$billTo->lastName   = isset($_POST["lastName"]) ? $_POST["lastName"] : "";
$billTo->street1    = isset($_POST["street1"]) ? $_POST["street1"] : "";
$billTo->city       = isset($_POST["city"]) ? $_POST["city"] : "";
$billTo->state      = isset($_POST["state"]) ? $_POST["state"] : "";
$billTo->postalCode = isset($_POST["postalCode"]) ? $_POST["postalCode"] : "";
$billTo->country    = isset($_POST["country"]) ? $_POST["country"] : "";
$billTo->email      = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";

$request->billTo = $billTo;
```

#### EDIT:

Null coalescing, as mentioned in the comments, is a new feature in PHP7, and according to PHP manual,

```
The null coalescing operator(??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise returns its second operand.
```

To apply this to my answer above, you can replace the above code snippet with:

```
$billTo = new stdClass();
$billTo->firstName  = $_POST["firstName"] ?? "";
$billTo->lastName   = $_POST["lastName"] ?? "";
$billTo->street1    = $_POST["street1"] ?? "";
$billTo->city       = $_POST["city"] ?? "";
$billTo->state      = $_POST["state"] ?? "";
$billTo->postalCode = $_POST["postalCode"] ?? "";
$billTo->country    = $_POST["country"] ?? "";
$billTo->email      = $_POST["email"] ?? "";

$request->billTo = $billTo;
```

The two code snippets above will have the same output.

And just to clean MyForm.php, you can remove the `value` attribute in all your text areas.